# Cannot create record after ember-data upgrade

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

After the latest ember-data 1.0 release, I have had some problems creating records. I read in the release notes - https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md that:

```
App.NewPostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Post.createRecord();
  }
});
```

is now replaced with:

```
App.NewPostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('post');
  }
});
```

However in my controller I cannot figure it out how to call the createRecord() method, as I have something like this:

```
addNewTrip:function() {
    var tripDeparature = this.get("tripDeparature");
    var tripArrival = this.get("tripArrival");
    var trips = App.Trips.createRecord({
         tripDeparature: tripDeparature,
         tripArrival:tripArrival,
         isCompleted:false
    });
    trip.save();
    this.set("tripDeparture","");
    this.set("tripArrival","");
}
```

And it throws an error: ...has no method 'createRecord' (which is expected after the new release), but I cannot figure it out how to call the createRecord correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `App.Trips.createRecord(parameters ...)` use `this.store.createRecord('trips', parameters ...)`.

Your code will become:

```
addNewTrip:function() {
    var tripDeparature = this.get("tripDeparature");
    var tripArrival = this.get("tripArrival");
    var trip = this.store.createRecord('trips', {
         tripDeparature: tripDeparature,
         tripArrival:tripArrival,
         isCompleted:false
    });
    trip.save();
    this.set("tripDeparture","");
    this.set("tripArrival","");
}
```

Comment: This. The store is now injected into all routes and controllers, and all CRUD operations should now go through this (as I understand it). So no more App.Model.create/find/foo.

Comment: Thank you, Marcio! Helped a lot!

Comment: But... how do I get another store object? this.store only gives the controllers model. How do I get another model? Say in a playlist, how does one create a new song?